# Interpreting the output of SET STATISTICS TIME, specifically Execution Time: Elapsed Time

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-performance

SQL Server 2008 (not R2), remotely hosted database. SSMS 2008R2.

I have been experiencing extremely long query times for some very very simple queries, such as this one which in this case took 77 seconds to complete
`UPDATE Balances SET InUse WHERE BalanceId = 6;`

The problem is quite sporadic, in that I can run the same query again and again and it will run in less than one second, but once in a while it will take a exorbitant amount of time to complete. Below is the message output from the above query with SET STATISTICS TIME ON and SET STATISTICS IO ON.

```
SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 0 ms.
SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 0 ms.
Table 'Balances'. Scan count 1, logical reads 38, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 0 ms.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.
Table 'BalanceRevisionsAuto'. Scan count 10, logical reads 267106, physical reads 77634, read-ahead reads 80251, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 2312 ms,  elapsed time = 77219 ms.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.
Table 'BalanceRevisionsAuto'. Scan count 0, logical reads 1, physical reads 0, read ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Assets'. Scan count 0, logical reads 2, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Balances'. Scan count 1, logical reads 38, physical reads 2, read-ahead reads 18, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 61 ms.

(1 row(s) affected)

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 2312 ms,  elapsed time = 77300 ms.

(1 row(s) affected)
```

I am confused on a few points:

1. Why are the other tables "BalanceRevisionsAuto", "Assets" showing up as having logical reads executed against them in this query? There are no foreign key relationships between the tables that would necessitate checking the others during an update.
2. Under SQL Server Execution Times, what does it mean that elapsed time = 77300ms? I've [read](http://www.practicalsqldba.com/2013/07/sql-server-performance-tuning_17.html) that the "elapsed time includes these elements:

   - signal wait time
   - wait time to complete the IO operation and
   - time taken to transfer the output to the client
     Does the last one of these include network transfer time?

   Does "elapsed time" include the time to get the data back to the requesting computer? It would seem that the article I have quoted says it does. Is there any way to separate out this time?
3. Why does "SQL Server Execution Times" appear six times? Are these for each part of the query plan?

Comment: Is it any chance you have triggers on `Balances` table ? It would explain (1)...

Comment: Triggers would explain both #1 and #3 (you will see an entry for each query).  It will likely also explain the length of query time.  For #2, elapsed time is exactly that: the total time from when you hit execute until SSMS actually gives you a final output.

Comment: Yes, thank you, I just just came back to report I'd found the reason, but a1ex07 and Dave figure it out first. Thanks and +1
I am still most concerned with the answer to number 2...